Proyecto recien migradono no detecta Datatables
Por cambios en el licenciamiento de algunos servidores, he tenido que migrar mis soluciones de un servidor viejo "Server A" (Windows Server 2016) a nuevo servidor "Server B" (Windows Server 2022), para trasladar las soluciones copie el directorio en el que estaban alojados las soluciones, que era en una particion en el disco del Server A y lo pegue en una ruta del disco C del Server B, en el Server B realice la instalacion de Visual Studio la cual quedo 17.10.4 y el Server A 17.5.4, al ejecutar uno de estos proyectos, lanza en consola un mensaje de error al hacer uso de DataTable, como si no estuviera realizando la importacion de Datatables, pero el codigo no ha cambiado, en el Server A el proyecto corre sin problemas, pero en el Server B, no esta encontrando DataTables, la forma en la que estoy importando es de esta manera:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-2.0.8/af-2.7.0/b-3.0.2/cr-2.0.3/date-1.5.2/fc-5.0.1/fh-4.0.1/kt-2.12.1/r-3.0.2/rg-1.5.0/rr-1.5.0/sc-2.4.3/sb-1.7.1/sp-2.3.1/sl-2.0.3/datatables.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-2.0.8/af-2.7.0/b-3.0.2/cr-2.0.3/date-1.5.2/fc-5.0.1/fh-4.0.1/kt-2.12.1/r-3.0.2/rg-1.5.0/rr-1.5.0/sc-2.4.3/sb-1.7.1/sp-2.3.1/sl-2.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

Y el error que aroja en consola es el siguiente:

Pareciera que DataTables esta cargando antes que JQuery, pero no he cambiado nada dentro de la logica del codigo, en el Server A, este mismo codigo está funcionando.

Saludos. Da un vistazo al sitio; al parecer ya no es datatable sino DataTable y quizás algunos otros cambios por la versión. Así mismo ya que los CSS y JS no son locales, verifica que dentro de la red no exista política de seguridad que bloquee esos sitios. Mira en Network (de donde tomaste el screenshot) que los JS y CSS sí se carguen.

@RobertoLeOr efectivamente era esto, muchas gracias.
